# on click, add class to alternative div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, `div1` and `div2`. On clicking any of these div, I want to remove class `.active` from it and add that class to the other div.

I'm trying following code, but I cant figure out how to add the class to the other div which is not clicked. Thanks.

```js
$('.div').click(function() {
  $(".div").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
.div2 {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div div1 active">div1</div>
<div class="div div2">div2</div>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vLLtLwxy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are only two elements, you could just use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kf2kr8pw/)

```
$('.div').click(function(){
    $(".div").toggleClass("active");                     
});
```

---

Similarly, it's worth pointing out that you could also negate one of the elements using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sn2dLrg/)

```
$('.div').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $('.div').not(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Plus one on mentioning `not`. It's much less used in cases like these, however it is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it. Just a related question, is it possible to use fadeIn with the toggleClass in above example?

Comment: @user1355300 Not directly. There is [a `.fadeToggle()` method](http://jsfiddle.net/x1vsux5b/). You could also use a CSS3 transition in combination with `.toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `toggleClass` on both the `div`'s as follows :

```
$(function () {    
     $('.div').click(function(){
        $(".div").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

See the snippet below :

```js
$(function () {    
     $('.div').click(function(){
        $(".div").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.div1{
    background: green;
    display: none;
}

.div2{
    background: red;
    display: none; 
}

.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div div1 active">I'm div1</div>
<div class="div div2">I'm div2</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of highlighting the next (adjacent) element of the one clicked on:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div:active').removeClass('active');
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (0 == next.length) {
        next = $('div:first');
    }
    $(next).addClass('active');
});
```

Cycle between 7 divs: http://jsfiddle.net/k0oq4hd5/1/

Cycle between 3 divs: http://jsfiddle.net/k0oq4hd5/2/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I hadn't noticed your answer -- here I added a different way of doing things, hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .addClass method [(MDN Docs):](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
<div id="div1" class="div active">div1</div>
<div id="div2"class="div">div2</div>

 $('.div').click(function(){
    $("#div1").removeClass("active");
    $("#div2").addClass("active");                    
});
```

Using ID selectors instead of class selectors ensures if you add more `<div>` elements they are not toggled like if you used [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: This does work. However, if you wish to extend it then you will have to write extra code. In essence, this is not really the best solution.